# Spring Batch, how to wrap a method inside Job

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

i'm totally new to Spring Batch.

I'm facing many problems since every tutorial or guide i'm reading is based on a previous version of Spring Batch, where a lot of methods and logics are deprecated.

I'm developing a Spring backend, which processes infos from a Mongo database and uses it to do various things to save on some collections in my database.

My boss wants me to wrap this Service's method inside a Job.

So, i should not use every bit of power that Spring Batch provides to us.

I simply want a Job to execute this method called generateZones().

I'm facing a lot of problems here, since there are many things to consider (JobRepository, StepBuilder, PlatformTransactionManager), but i also feel i should not use these kind of things to perform such a basic operation.

Anyone could direct me in this?

Comment: Why? If you aren't going to leverage Spring Batch why on earth use it. And yes you need all those things for the spring batch metadata.

Comment: My boss wanted me to use Spring Batch for scheduling. But i also found out that Batch doesn't provide scheduling (Spring does). However, i'd still want to use Batch in the simplest way possible, just to execute this method to benefit from Batch. But i'm finding a lot of difficulties since there's lack of tutorials or guides. The documentation doesn't seem to help too

Comment: You won't benefit from anything here, nor is SPring Batch using scheduling it is for providing Batch capabilities. Just use basic spring scheduling you don't need batch, in fact it will only make your life harder in this case.

Comment: That's what i was thinking. I will report it to my boss and hope he understands ahahah

Comment: If it is scheduling you want and some information you might want to look into [JobRunR](https://www.jobrunr.io/en/) which is for scheduling jobs and recording some metadata about that.

Comment: @TrySoHard If the use-case is for scheduling then you can check spring-scheduler or quartz-scheduler. I think spring-scheduler also uses the quartz internally. It is quite simple to setup a quartz scheduler.